# Alluvial plot for three variabes

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

From a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close","close"), 
           stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
           newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))
```

How do I need to transform the data in order to have an alluvial plot [image: like this]

where the two columns are stock and newspaper and the link is the frequency of status column

Comment: Hi! The data.frame provided seams to be too small or missing the frequency column. 
I am suggesting this because the code for the desired figure can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the data provided, it is difficult to know exactly what has to be plotted. I suggest this approach inspired by [this blog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html) on alluvial plots by the R library `ggalluvial`:

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close", "close"), 
                 stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
                 newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))

# Count the number of occurance for each alluvial
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(stock, newspaper, status) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) 

# Define the factors
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels = c("open", "open/close", "close"))
df$stock <- factor(df$stock, levels = c("google", "amazon", "yahoo"))
df$newspaper <- factor(df$newspaper, levels = c("times", "newyork", "london"))

# Plot the alluvial as in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html#alluvia-wide-format
ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(y = n, axis1 = stock, axis2 = newspaper)) +
  ggalluvial::geom_alluvium(aes(fill = status), width = 1/12) +
  ggalluvial::geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  ggplot2::geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits = c("stock", "newspaper"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Alluvial-Test")
```